# How to install ldap2 using xampp?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, xampp, adldap

I have been trying to install ldap2 by following the instruction from [this](https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2).
I have already done this step:
"Adldap2 utilizes composer for installation. Insert "adldap2/adldap2": "6.1.*" in your composer.json file:

"require": {
    "adldap2/adldap2": "6.1.*"
}"
I also have enabled ldap in both php.ini files by uncommenting them but then when I run the command: composer update on windows cmd, I get the following error:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.9 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.8 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.7 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.6 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.5 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.4 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.3 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.2 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.10 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
 ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.1 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.0 requires ext-ldap * -> the requested PHP extension
ldap is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for adldap2/adldap2 v6.1.* -> satisfiable by adldap2/
adldap2[v6.1.0, v6.1.1, v6.1.10, v6.1.2, v6.1.3, v6.1.4, v6.1.5, v6.1.6, v6.1.7,
 v6.1.8, v6.1.9].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PH
P in CLI mode.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Please state them as text, 'cause the image doesn'T work

Comment: I just did. Sorry I had no idea that the image link wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the LDAP-Extension for PHP installed and activated in your CLI environment as well as in your apache-environment. A quick call to a random search-engine found this for example: https://serverfault.com/questions/72447/how-can-i-enable-ldap-in-php-windows-server-2008